# Connect multiple smartwatches with one smartphone/tablet

Tags: android, wear-os, wearables

Is it possible to connect multiple android smartwatches (4-5) to a single tablet/smartwatch and communicate on those watches with each other in a custom made app? The purpose is to communicate with employees with wearable devices in a customized android app for a business environment (the employees would receive tasks from a backend system and they can accept/decline those tasks and should be able to send information about their accepted tasks back). I would like to use a single tablet/smartwatch to lower the cost of a dedicated smartphone for each wearable). Is this possible with android wear or does anyone now an alternative to create a solution like this?

Comment: Sounds cool, but as far as I know, most of android smartwatches communicates through bluetooth right? So even if that would work, the range between employees and tablet would need to be small.

Comment: @UncleChris virtually all newer Wear watches have Wifi - which ought to work fine for a use case like this - and with Wear 2.0, LTE support should become fairly common as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. All Wear devices paired to a given phone or tablet) exist on a single "network", and communications using the Wear APIs can travel freely among them.

A couple of specifics, with documentation links:

- Updates passed to the [Data API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html) will appear more-or-less simultaneously on all connected devices.
- Using the [Message API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html), you can send data or actions from one device to another (like from the single phone to a specific watch, or vice versa), specified by its unique Node ID.